# I wanna combine the values based on Time columns. like 2016-11 's value should be combined

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

[image: pd.df]

for eg: in the pic the 'Time' with same value ie. 2016-11 which has the two separate values I want that to be added in a separate column. I am using pandas here.I'm a beginner so a simple reply is better.

Comment: can you please post the raw data instead of image

Comment: Check 11 Q/A in dupe

Comment: you can do a groupby and sum on revenue to get the value

Comment: You can do something as simple as df.groupby('Time')['Revenue'].sum()